# objc custom view with nib not visible on tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an UITableViewCell contain a custom view, the custom view contains two label. The view hierarchical likes that:

                                 `|---Label 1
XIB---MyTableViewCell---MyView---|
                                 |---Label 2`

But run application, just shown 'MyView', Label 1 and Label 2 not visible! If I wrote code on viewDidLoad, take 'MyView' as viewController.view's subview, the label 1 and 2 is appeared. Hope you can help me.
[image]

Comment: here you use two different nib, one for cell, one for myview. I saw you didn't add label in cell nib. may you add that in myview.nib?

Comment: @SolaWing Yes, the lable belongs to MyView.nib. and MyView.nib as viewController.subView works fine

Comment: so this is the problem. cell.nib only contains myview, it don't contain myview.nib. you need to add label in cell.nib. or create label in myview programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

Create `MyView` like this:

```
class MyView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var _label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var _label2: UILabel!

// Our custom view from the XIB file
var view: UIView!

//MARK: - Setup -
private func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    // Make the view stretch with containing view
    view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
}

private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

func setLabeles(lbl1: String, lbl2: String) {
    _label1!.text = lbl1
    _label2!.text = lbl2
}
}
```

[image]
Make `Label1` and `Label2` outlet to respective ones.

Then add it to custom `tableViewCell` as:

[image]
(Pink colour is for highlighting!)
Make `My View` outlet.

Custom cell code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var _myView: MyView!

class func identifier() -> String {
    return "CustomTableViewCellId"
}

class func nib() -> UINib {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    return nib
}

//MARK: Public Methods
func setCellIndexLabel(index: Int) {
    _myView!.setLabeles("lbl1: \(index)", lbl2: "lbl2: \(index)")
}
```

Then there is no need to do extra anything in table view, just do:
In `viewDidLoad()`-

```
tableView!.registerNib(CustomTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomTableViewCell.identifier())
//then
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Configure the cell...
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CustomTableViewCell.identifier(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.setCellIndexLabel(indexPath.row)

    return cell
}
```

And you will get this:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

---

Forgive me for providing `swift` code, but it's not much different that `objective-c`!

Comment: This solution can draw correctly but has another problem, MyView's custom-class (in Interface Builder setting) is UIView not 'MyView' , so can't use the outlet property label1 and label2, If set custom-class is "MyView" instead 'UIView', cause Infinite loop when call loadViewFromNib.

Comment: @WilliamSterling I don't get you actually for `Infinite loop`, but I edited my answer with outlets!

Comment: Thank you so much @DashAndRest